# Average calculates weighted average in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Could someone explain me why the AVG() function gives me a weighted average in my code?

```
SELECT s.stud_id, s.country, SUM(e.paid) AS totalpaid
    INTO #totalpaid 
    FROM oc.students AS s
    JOIN oc.enrollment AS e ON s.stud_id = e.stud_id
GROUP BY s.country ,s.stud_id;

SELECT DISTINCT s.country, ROUND(AVG(t.totalpaid) OVER (PARTITION BY s.country),0) AS avg_country
    FROM #totalpaid t
    JOIN oc.students s ON t.stud_id = s.stud_id
    JOIN oc.enrollment e ON e.stud_id = s.stud_id;
```

For example in the case of Malta Student12 attended 1 course and paid EUR45,Student837 attended 7 courses and paid EUR294 in total. I would like to have a simple (45+294)/2 calculation for the average however the system calculates like (1*45+7*294)/8. What am I doing wrong?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second query, when you join your temp table back to `enrollment`, it's generating one row per class; which is where the multiple values in the `totalpaid` column are coming from.

The second query isn't using any columns that aren't already in the temp table, so you don't need those joins at all. This should produce what you're looking for.

```
SELECT 
  t.country, 
  ROUND(AVG(t.totalpaid) OVER (PARTITION BY t.country),0) AS avg_country
FROM #totalpaid t
GROUP BY 
  t.country;
```

Comment: Yes you're totally right. However the code what you wrote gives me an error.
This works:
{SELECT DISTINCT
  t.country, 
  ROUND(AVG(t.totalpaid) OVER (PARTITION BY t.country),0) AS avg_country
FROM #totalpaid t
GROUP BY 
  t.country, t.totalpaid;}
But without DISTINCT there are multiple values again.

Comment: Ok in the meantime I find the solution, I totally over-complicated. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are joining your tables twice.

By putting together the `INSERT` and `SELECT` statements your query is equivalent to:

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT s.country, 
  ROUND(AVG(t.totalpaid) OVER (PARTITION BY s.country),0) AS avg_country
FROM (
  SELECT s.stud_id, s.country, SUM(e.paid) AS totalpaid
  FROM oc.students AS s
  JOIN oc.enrollment AS e ON s.stud_id = e.stud_id
  GROUP BY s.country ,s.stud_id    
) t
JOIN oc.students s ON t.stud_id = s.stud_id
JOIN oc.enrollment e ON e.stud_id = s.stud_id
```

There you can clearly see the table `students` and `enrollment` are joined twice. That would produce a skewed average function.

Comment: I see. But how could I manage the problem without that? Sorry if it's very basic but I cannot see the other way. Could you give me a hint,please?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT s.country, sum(e.paid) / count(DISTINCT s.stud_id) as average
FROM oc.students s 
JOIN oc.enrollment e ON e.stud_id = s.stud_id
GROUP BY s.country;
```

Comment: Code-only answers tend to be considered low quality, both for the current user asking the question and for future users with similar issues. An explanation of your solution adds significant value to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the meantime I found the solution:

```
 SELECT
      country,
      ROUND(AVG(totalpaid) OVER (PARTITION BY country),0) AS avg_country
    FROM #totalpaid;
```

Super easy :)